# Results are not same from Numpy function as array when on ubuntu and other operating system?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

have a function that fills a list of lists and return a numpy array by the asarray method.

```
L = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

myarray = asarray(L)
```

The function nicely works as it ought do under OS X, giving a ndarray with shape=(7,). Under Ubuntu the very same code gives a zero-Rank numpy array with shape=(). However, I can recover the saved data by calling

```
myarray[()] or myarray[()].[i]
that indicates that myarray is a list instead. Indeed

In [32]: type(myarray)
Out[32]: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [33]: type(myarray[...])
Out[33]: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [34]: type(myarray[()])
Out[34]: <type 'list'>
```

Any help or hint?

Comment: I suspect this is probably due to different versions of `numpy` on your different machines

Comment: Use `print(repr(myarray))`.  This should give more information about the array.  I get `array([], shape=(7, 0), dtype=float64)` for your first example.   But I can also generate a `array([list([]), list([]), list([]) ...], dtype=object)` array - an array of lists.

Comment: Creating an object dtype array via copy-n-paste can be tricky if the sublists are all the same size.